# How to create column for selected parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have this query that pulls results based on the selected LOV parameter: nvl(:Role, role))

```
SELECT role,subject 
FROM HS_SUBJECT_INCIDENTS 
WHERE entitlement not in(select entitlement from HS_SUBJECT_INCIDENTS where role in nvl(:Role, role))
AND subject in (select subject from HS_SUBJECT_INCIDENTS where role in nvl(:Role, role))
```

So if the user selected 'Finance' for the parameter value, the results now show:

```
|   Role    | Subject  | 
------------------------
| Marketing | Business |  
| Marketing | Business |  
| Analytics | Business |
```

I want the results to show like this:

```
|   Role    | Subject  | SelectedParameter |
--------------------------------------------
| Marketing | Business |  Finance          |
| Marketing | Business |  Finance          |
| Analytics | Business |  Finance          |
```

What do I have to put in the select statement to include a column for the parameter value that was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it:

```
SELECT role, subject, :Role as SelectedParameter
FROM . . .
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I was putting in the whole nvl(:Role, role))